# Get Intent Ranking List in Rasa Core/NLU

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

When we run the command:

```
rasa shell nlu
```

we get, a dictionary in which one attribute is *intent_ranking* which is list of dictionaries containing information about intents sorted by the confidence score. Is there any way to get this list during normal run of the program in my custom actions:

```
rasa shell
```

My main aim is to fetch the top intents along with their confidence score and then perform some preprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I understood how to solve this issue:
In your customs actions you can can fetch the intent ranking by the following code:

```
intent_ranking = tracker.latest_message['intent_ranking']
```

This particular code will help you fetch the list of intents sorted by the confidence score in a descending order. The output then can be used for further preprocessing.